# How to implement wide one dimensional convolution in cntk

Tags: cntk

I'd like to implement the wide type of one dimensional convolution (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2188v1.pdf) in CNTK. Is there a built in method for that or how should I play with the parameters of Convolution() to implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you not specify your strides as 4,1 as opposed to like 2,2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try padding your data with zero and then use C.ops.convolution().

Comment: Thanks! I think this is should be the answer for 12 filters of width 3, stride =1 in Python:                                                                                                   Convolution((1,3), 12, init=glorot_uniform(), activation=relu, pad=True)(input)